# kotlin select between 2 imageview n times using for loop

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

how can i make user to choose(by clicking on image) between 2 images n times using for loop?

below, i have created an array of 4 drawable images and set it to rank2.
on each loop, user will choose one between 2 images, then selected image is saved in rank1 array.
because there are only 4 drawables right now, it will only loop 2 times.

```
val imageView1 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView1);
val imageView2 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2);
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView);

var rank2 = mutableListOf(R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4)
val rank1: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()

var x = 0;
while(x<2) {//run it 2 times
  var temp = arrayOf(rank2[x*2], rank2[(x*2)+1]);

  imageView1.setImageResource(temp[0]);
  imageView2.setImageResource(temp[1]);

  imageView1.setOnClickListener{
    rank1.add(temp[0]);
    x++;
  }
  imageView1.setOnClickListener{
    rank1.add(temp[1]);
    x++;
  }
}
```

but, this one falls into infinite loop.
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `while` loop. A counting variable is all you need.

```
var rank2 = mutableListOf(R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4)
val rank1: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()

imageView1.setImageResource(rank2[0]);
imageView2.setImageResource(rank2[1]);

var x = 0

imageView1.setOnClickListener{
  if (x < 2) {
    rank1.add(rank2[2 * x])
    imageView1.setImageResource(rank2[2 * (x + 1)])
    imageView2.setImageResource(rank2[2 * (x + 1) + 1])
    x++
  }
}
imageView2.setOnClickListener{
  if (x < 2) {
    rank1.add(rank2[2 * x + 1])
    imageView1.setImageResource(rank2[2 * (x + 1)])
    imageView2.setImageResource(rank2[2 * (x + 1) + 1])
    x++
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a recursive method instead of a cycle that calls itself nLoops times. Try something like this:

```
fun c(b: Int, nLoops: Int) {
    if (b!=nLoops) {
        var x = b;
        var temp = arrayOf(rank2[x * 2], rank2[(x * 2) + 1]);

        imageView1.setImageResource(temp[0]);
        imageView2.setImageResource(temp[1]);

        imageView1.setOnClickListener
        {
            rank1.add(temp[0]);
            x++;
            c(x, nLoops);
        }
        imageView1.setOnClickListener
        {
            rank1.add(temp[1]);
            x++;
            c(x, nLoops);
        }
    }
}
```

When you run somethink like this with b=0 and nLoops = 2 it will execute your code only ehwn you press the image for 2 times.